# DBGrid is not refreshing after deleting record from database

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, dbgrid

I wondering why my DBGridEh (descendant DBGrid) is not refreshing after I deleted a record in the database using the following MRE. You will find my 4 attempts commented below but no luck. The deletion basically works but the DBGrid does not update or disconnects from datasource.

```
procedure TForm9.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //cds1.DisableControls; //attempt 1 failed. It deletes the record but not changes on the DBGrid
  uq1.SQL.Clear;
  uq1.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM mymachine WHERE ListID = :Pid';
  uq1.Params.ParamByName('Pid').Value := cds1.FieldByName('ListID').AsInteger;
  uq1.ExecSQL;
  //cds1.EnableControls;  //attempt 1 failed. It deletes the record but not changes on the DBGrid
  //cds1.Active := False; //attempt 2 failed. "SQL Statement doesn't return rows." but it deletes and cleared the data on the DBGrid (seemed disconnected from datasource) 
  //cds1.Active := True;  //attempt 2 failed. "SQL Statement doesn't return rows." but it deletes and cleared the data on the DBGrid (seemed disconnected from datasource) 
  //cds1.Close;           //attempt 3 failed. "SQL Statement doesn't return rows." but it deletes and cleared the data on the DBGrid (seemed disconnected from datasource) 
  //cds1.Open;            //attempt 3 failed. "SQL Statement doesn't return rows." but it deletes and cleared the data on the DBGrid (seemed disconnected from datasource)
  //cds1.Refresh;         //attempt 4 failed. "SQL Statement doesn't return rows." but it deletes and DBGrid data remains
end;
```

**UPDATE VCL.FILE**

```
  object dgh1: TDBGridEh

  object ucn1: TUniConnection
    ProviderName = 'mySQL'
    Port = 3306
    Database = 'manufacturingmngtsystem'
    Username = 'root'
    Server = 'localhost'
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 16
    Top = 200
  end
  object mup1: TMySQLUniProvider

  end
  object uq1: TUniQuery
    Connection = ucn1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'Select * From mymachine')
  end
  object dsp1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = uq1
  end
  object cds1: TClientDataSet
    Active = True
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'dsp1'
    object intgrfldcds1ListID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'ListID'
    end
    object strngfldcds1Name: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Required = True
      Size = 36
    end
    object strngfldcds1Description: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Description'
      Size = 209
    end
    object strngfldcds1Status: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Status'
      Required = True
      FixedChar = True
      Size = 8
    end
  end
  object ds1: TDataSource
    DataSet = cds1
  end
end
```

Comment: If your DBGridEh is connected to `cds1`, why would you expect the grid to update?  Nothing your code is now doing should affect the contents of `cds1`, so why would what the grid displays change?  Anyway, if you want help with this, please say a) that datatype your uq1 is and b) what SQL database type your uq1 is connected to.

Comment: Simply because the user would want to see in the DBGrid that the record selected in it has gone. The uq1 datatype is integer and the database type is mysql.

Comment: `SQL database type your uq1 is connected to` is Integer. If this is what you mean.

Comment: Does anything speak against just calling `cds1.Delete`?

Comment: You should update your question with the details asked in the comment instead of adding a comment with your answer. This is how questions are enhanced. I think that when MartynA ask "Why would you expect the grid to update" he is not asking why a user want to see the grid updated but he is asking "what in your code would makes the grid to an update". He explain why...

Comment: I meant what Delphi component type is your `uq1`.  Also which Delphi component type are you using to get data from your mysql database into `cds1`.  I'm asking these things because it seems rather likely that you are going about thid=s in completely the wrong way.  Which Delphi version btw?

Comment: @MartynA I have provided the VCL.File in my update above for the details you wanted to see. I have deleted some lines in it as SO does not allow so much code. I hope you get all the details in there.

Comment: @UweRaabe cds1.delete actually works! It works with `cds1.DisableControls/EnableControls` or `cds1.Close/Open` I think you have solved my problem already. Of course with the `cds1.ApplyUpdates(0)`.

Comment: From what you've said to @UweRaabe, it seems that you'd previously missed the point that when using a `CDS` and `TDataSetProvider` to work with a SQL database, you simply perform the operations you wanrt on the `CDS` and call its `ApplyUpdates` method to propagate the changes back to your SQL database.  You shouldn't need to do things like use `uq1` **at all**.  Google yourself a tutorial on using TDataSetProvider with TClientDataSet and study it.

Comment: @MartynA Yes I agree. I have been using cds in all my database manipulation. I just missed the cds1.delete and I opted to UniQuery instead. Anyhow, sometimes this happens to anyone when you're in the box with the problem you can't see the solution. This serves a lesson to me.

Comment: @UweRaabe can you post a quick answer so I can mark it answered and anyone with the same issue may also learn swiftly.

Comment: I'm glad @UweRaabe set you straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the grid is connected to the dataset `cds1`, a simple `cds1.Delete` will do the trick. This might have to be followed by a call to `cds1.ApplyUpdates` to forward the changes to the underlying database.